# VB6 inserting file path into SQL FROM clause

Tags: sql, vb6, ado

I am working in VB6 on a Windows 7 desktop to read and work on text files and have run into a problem passing variable to a SELECT statement. The code I have is :

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cm As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & App.Path & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited( )"""

inputFile = "C:\test data\test data.asc"

Set cm = New ADODB.Command
cm.ActiveConnection = conn
cm.CommandType = adCmdText

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & inputFile 
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cm, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

The problem is that the path name to the input file contains spaces and when I run the code above, it fails at the rs.OPen line with an error saying Syntax error in FROM clause.
If the path in inputFile does not contain spaces, everything works without a problem.

I have tried many combinations of " ' [] etc around the inputFile but always get the syntax error or another error saying that inputFile.txt can not be found.

Can anyone give me the correct method for handling path/files names with spaces in an SQL statement please?

Comment: FYI when adding code to a question it goes between the tick marks or indent it by 4 spaces

Comment: What is the name of the table you are trying to select from?  It looks like you're trying to select from a file in the file system, which makes no sense.

Comment: I am trying to read the data from a text file. As I said, if the path in inputFile does not contain spaces, I can read the text file data without any problems. Once the rs is open, I use rs.GetRows to put the data into an array which I then process.

Comment: Have you tried `cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM '" & inputFile & "'"`

Comment: @recursive *Correcting my earlier comment following input from Bob in his answer.* It makes sense. Using the Text Installable ISAM for the Jet 4.0 OLEDB Provider allows you to query text files as if they were database tables.

Answer (score 3):

The value supplied for Data Source should always be quoted to avoid such problems.  You can use either the quotation mark " or apostrophe ' to do this, much as you did for the Extended properties value.

Then to use a file name within the Data Source directory as a table name *at least* "quote" it using brackets [ ], and preferably replace the . for the file extension by the # character.

There is no "OLEDB Provider for text files" but your example shows use of the Jet 4.0 OLEDB Provider with its Text Installable ISAM, which is just fine.

[Processing Text Databases](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=298926) offers a lot of information on this topic in general, using VBScript for most examples but it pretty much all applies to VB6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently spaces in the filename [should work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/17/syntax-error-in-from-clause-when-using-text-based-datasources.aspx) if you use square brackets `[`  `]`.

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & inputFile & "]"
```

You say in the question you've tried square brackets - could you double check? I don't know about spaces in the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a memory from the distant past and if I remember right the data source is the folder the file is held in and in the select you just have the file name without the path.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cm As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & App.Path & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited( )"""

inputFile = "test data.asc"

Set cm = New ADODB.Command
cm.ActiveConnection = conn
cm.CommandType = adCmdText

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & inputFile & "]"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cm, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

(assuming the file is in `App.Path`)